# Error Expected a ';' in for statement

Tags: c

This is my simple for loop code:

```
for(int i=0; i < sisi ; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j <= sisi-i; j++)
    {
        if(j != sisi-i)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int b=0; b < 2i+1; b++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The error is caught at line 6, it says 'error expected a ";"', but i think the code is ok and no wrong grammar inside the code... But why is it occured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your for loop condition `2i` is invalid expressión.
It should be like this:

```
for(int b = 0; b < (2 * i) + 1; b++)
```

Comment: Actually, it is valid, just not what he intended... I think.

Comment: [I'm begginging to think I'm not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). There's no mention of an `i` suffix, so I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The error is this line:

```
for(int b=0;b<2i+1;b++)
```

If you wanted 2x i then use this:

```
int b;
for(b = 0; b < (2*i)+1; b++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply by putting a number next to a variable. It has to be `2 * i`. You'll want to change `2i + 1` to `2 * i + 1`.